# In org-mode, undo the effects of :results pp

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In my org-files I usually always enable pretty-printing at the top because I find it preferrable to Org's default of trying to fit output into tables and whatnot. But I have now hit a snag.

In a clean `emacs -Q`:

```
#+name: session-name
#+begin_src elisp
"The name of a session"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: session-name
: "The name of a session"

#+begin_src elisp
(org-sbe session-name)
#+end_src
#+RESULTS:
: "\"The name of a session\""
```

The problem, as you can see, is that we end up with quotes in the value passed on to other code blocks.

Simply trying to supplant the header-arg `:results` with a code block local one does not help, which is wierd:

```
#+name: session-name-2
#+begin_src elisp :results value
"A second session"
#+end_src
#+RESULTS: session-name-2
: "A second session"
```

I have only found two ways around this issue:

1. Remove the :results header block for the subtree

   ```
   ** A subtree
   #+PROPERTY: header-args :results value

   #+name: session-name-3
   #+begin_src elisp
   "A third session"
   #+end_src
   #+RESULTS: session-name-3
   : A third session
   ```

   But that has side effects like bash blocks resulting in their return code

   ```
   #+begin_src bash
   ls /
   #+end_src
   #+RESULTS:
   : 0
   ```
2. Telling the org-mode to output the result in raw mode, which breaks reevaluation.

   ```
   #+name: session-name-4
   #+begin_src elisp :results raw
   "A fourth session"
   #+end_src
   #+RESULTS: session-name-4
   A fourth session
   ```

Comment: Did you try `:results drawer` instead of `:results raw`?

Comment: No, that also works! Have you any idea why?

Comment: See the `Format` section of [Results of Evaluation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to explicitly only apply the pretty-printing to some languages like bash

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:bash+ :results pp

#+name: session-name-5
#+begin_src elisp 
"A fifth session"
#+end_src
#+RESULTS: session-name-5
: A fifth session

#+begin_src elisp
(org-sbe session-name-5)
#+end_src
#+RESULTS:
: A fifth session


#+begin_src bash
ls /
#+end_src
#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
bin
boot
...
#+end_example
```